# Wordpress theme php to pdf conversion error

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, fpdf, php-pdftk

I am using WordPress as my CMS.So there is a part where I am trying to generate a pdf file from php. I am using phpToPDF for generating the pdf file.I am doing so in a custom template page of wordpress and but getting this error:

---

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output 
started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Wordpress/wp-includes/general-
template.php:2942) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Suburban/wp-
content/themes/custom theme/phpToPDF.php on line 56
```

Tried to generate the pdf from core php and it worked...
But I need it in my wordpress site.

here is the code

---

```
<?php 
/* Template Name:test */
wp_head(); 
require("phpToPDF.php");

  $my_html="<div style=\"display:block;\">
  <div style=\"float:left; width:33%; text-align:left;\">
         Left Header Text
  </div>
  <div style=\"float:left; width:33%; text-align:center;\">
         Center Header Text
  </div>
  <div style=\"float:left; width:33%; text-align:right;\">
       Right Header Text
   </div>
   <br style=\"clear:left;\"/>
</div>";

   $pdf_options = array(
    "source_type" => 'php',
    "source" => $my_html,
    "action" => 'view',
    "save_directory" => '',
    "file_name" => 'pdf_test.pdf');
   phptopdf($pdf_options);

  // echo ("<a href='pdf_invoice.pdf'>Download Your PDF</a>");  
 wp_footer()
  ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: not much helpful

Comment: delete the close tag of php "?>" at first.if that didn't help, then provide function from this part "Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Suburban/wp-
content/themes/custom theme/phpToPDF.php on line 56"

Comment: how to "provide function from this part "Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Suburban/wp- content/themes/custom theme/phpToPDF.php on line 56"?
it contains this line of code "  header('Content-type: application/pdf');"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing wp_head(); and wp_footer() fixed this error